unable to start apache
i am new to ubuntu and this forum. i am planning to install new app and require apache 2. however the apache seem to not be working. when i type status apache2, i got the following respons:
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo apachectl[511237]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app_pengumuman.conf: Expected </Virtual>
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo apachectl[511215]: Action 'start' failed.
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo apachectl[511215]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 08 12:40:11 servertwo systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server. 


From the error message, "Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app_pengumuman.conf: Expected " Kindly edit your question and paste the contents of this file "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/app_pengumuman.conf"
